# About Duplicate in Object (Stool Legs)

Tags: modeling

Sorry for asking about very beginner question. But I have no idea how to solve it.

I am modeling a round stool look like this.

[image]

When I built one of leg, I don't have idea how to copy another one perfectly.
[image]

I tried to use mirror modifier. But it can not save the details of connection.

[image]

Is there any easy way to duplicate and paste to the correct part?
I only can think that delete the stool leg part one by one and paste it 3 times...

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most logical way to do it is to begin with a circle that is divisible by 3 (here a 18 vertex circle), create one stool leg, remove the other 2/3, activate the *Transform Pivot Point > 3D Cursor* and put the cursor at the origin of your object:

[image]

Then in *Edit* mode select all and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to duplicate and rotate 120°:

[image]

Then at the end select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* in order to merge all the overlapping vertices.

Comment: Thank you so much! I never thought about dividing the circle.